# How do I instruct Spring Boot Devtools where to find dependencies in a Maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-devtools

I've got a Spring Boot Maven project that creates an executable fat `.war`. I can run this `.war` using `java -jar` without any issues as all dependencies are located within the far `.war`.

However, I can't run the project with the Spring Boot Devtools using `mvn spring-boot:run` as it fails to find some dependencies at runtime and throws unhandled exceptions.

For example, we've got an indirect dependency on `jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar` which in turn has a dependency on `jaxb-api.2.3.1.jar`. Both `.jars` are present in the fat `.war` but if I run the project with `mvn spring-boot:run` it can find `jaxb-runtime` ok but fails to find `jaxb-api` with the message:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
```

Note, `jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar` is present in the maven cache at:

```
~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
```

however it seems to be looking for it in the same location as the parent `jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar` which is located at:

```
~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/
```

There's a long list of similar exceptions that follow this pattern. It's quite a large project but here are some of the versions we're using:

```
Spring Boot: 2.1.9.RELEASE
spring-boot-maven-plugin: 2.1.9.RELEASE
maven-compiler-plugin: 3.8.1
spring-boot-devtools: not specified in pom
```

Why does `spring-boot:run` not locate dependencies in the same way as the maven build? How can I instruct it where to find these dependencies?

Comment: It's difficult to point out the issue from the info provided. However, did you try deleting contents of the m2 repository and running `mvn clean install` in the root folder of the project after formatting m2 dir?

Comment: @noob_nerd, yes, I've tried that and it still doesn't work. We're also seeing this issue on a number of different machines.